# Array not carrying data forward

Tags: php

I have a form with 10 similar rows of data required. The form collects product codes, descriptions and quantities. I loop through 10 rows and use arrays to collect the information.

```
$code = array();
$description = array();
$quantity = array();

<?php
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    ?>
    <div class="quote-row">
        <div class="quote-id">
            <?php echo $i+1; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="quote-code">
            <input type="text" class="quotecode" name="<?php echo $code[$i]; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="quote-description">
            <input type="text" class="quotedescription" name="<?php echo $description[$i]; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="quote-quantity">
            <input type="text" class="quotequantity" name="<?php echo $quantity[$i]; ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

On the following page, I then use `$_POST['code'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['quantity']` to carry the data forward and attempt to use it.

My issue is that the data doesn't appear to be arriving?

Using the for loop, will I still be able to submit the form and take all the data forward?

Hope this is as informative as possible, thanks!

Comment: `var_dump` your $_POST array to see what you are sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving value of array in name attribute. Your array is empty so your name is empty too.

Try this:

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    ?>
    <div class="quote-row">
        <div class="quote-id">
            <?php echo $i+1; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="quote-code">
            <input type="text" class="quotecode" name="code[]" />
        </div>
        <div class="quote-description">
            <input type="text" class="quotedescription" name="description[]" />
        </div>
        <div class="quote-quantity">
            <input type="text" class="quotequantity" name="quantity[]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

**name[ ]** format automatically make your data an array.

Comment: I had a feeling it was something very basic, been a while since I did this and just made a mistake with the basics on the name and value attributes. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

There are several places where code needs to be updated to work as you expect it.

The most important being that the inputs are using the wrong attributes to store the name and value.

For example, the input element needs to look something like this for each of your inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="quotecode" name="code[]" value="<?php echo $code[$i]; ?>" />
```

After, adding a submit button and the surrounding form tags you can then proceed to inspect the variables in next page using PHPs $_POST or $_GET variables.

Answer (score 1):

The key to use with the `$_POST` array is whatever you put in the `name=""` attribute. Based on the code you provided the names aren't `code`, `description`, and `quantity` but whatever the actual codes, descriptions, and quantities of the items are. You probably want to do this instead:

```
$code = array();
$description = array();
$quantity = array();

<?php
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    ?>
    <div class="quote-row">
        <div class="quote-id">
            <?php echo $i+1; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="quote-code">
            <input type="text" class="quotecode" name="code[]" value="<?php echo $code[$i]; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="quote-description">
            <input type="text" class="quotedescription" name="description[]" value="<?php echo $description[$i]; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="quote-quantity">
            <input type="text" class="quotequantity" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $quantity[$i]; ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```